# Avoid strange error 'The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null', when fthe path is not null

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, cli, force-cli

When I execute the command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -u o14 -p CPQFields
```

I receive an error `The "path" argument must be of type string. Received null`, despite the path CPQFields is not null and contains many

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the culprit was invalid folder structure, when I copied fields, by accident I copied the `fields` folder only, while intended was `objects/Product2/fields`

The wrong folder structure which was raising the error that the path is null:

> CPQFields
>
> -fields
>
> -- Type__c.field-meta.xml

The correct folder structure which works well:

> CPQFields
>
> -objects/Product2/fields
>
> -- Type__c.field-meta.xml